# Python Decorators - __call__ in class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I was trying to understand Python decorators and I was trying to write an equivalent program to this one:

```
class myDecorator(object):
   def __init__(self, f):
      print ("inside myDecorator.__init__()")
      f() # Prove that function definition has completed

   def __call__(self):
      print ("inside myDecorator.__call__()")

@myDecorator
def aFunction():
   print ("inside aFunction()")

print ("Finished decorating aFunction()")

aFunction()
```

The problem is I am not understanding how the `__call__` method of class is being invoked by calling `aFunction()` in the end.

Is `aFunction()` being replaced by `myDecorator.__call__(aFunction)`.
Can you please help me? How would be an equivalent program without decorators?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The output of your code is

```
inside myDecorator.__init__()
inside aFunction()
Finished decorating aFunction()
inside myDecorator.__call__()
```

First, do you know, what this @ decorator syntax mean?

```
@decorator
def function(a):
    pass
```

is just another way of saying:

```
def function(a):
    pass
function = decorator(function)
```

So, in Your case

```
@myDecorator
def aFunction():
   print ("inside aFunction()")
```

means just

```
def aFunction():
    print ("inside aFunction()")
aFunction = myDecorator(aFunction)
```

At first, You basically create a new instance of myDecorator class, invoking it's constructor (__init__) and passing to it a aFunction function object. Then, it executes print and given function. Also, note that this is happening while the function is loaded by interpreter, not when it's executed, so in case you import something from this file, it will
execute then, not on use or call.

Then, executing the `aFunction()`, when aFunction is still refering to the myDecorator instance, makes it to call the `__call__` method of myDecorator, which executes. Note, that `f()` means the same as `f.__call__(f)` in this case, as `__call__` method is used to enable and override default object's calling behaviour (in simplification, any object is callable when it has `__call__` method defined).

If you want to execute aFunction when it's called, then you should assign it to instance variable in `__init__` and invoke it in `__call__` of myDecorator.

Answer (score 2):

That's the entire purpose of a decorator: to replace (or, more usually, wrap) a function with the function returned by the decorator. In your case, `aFunction` is being replaced with an instance of `myDecorator`, so when you call `aFunction()` you are really calling that instance: and in Python, calling a class instance invokes its `__call__` method.

Defining a decorated function is exactly equivalent to this:

```
def aFunction():
    print("inside aFunction()")
aFunction = myDecorator(aFunction)
```

Usually, of course, the wrapping function would call the original function after doing whatever it does.

Answer (score 1):

`afunction` is being replaced by an instance of the class `myDecorator`. The class has a `__call__` method, so the instance can be called like a function. Thus, assuming its signature is compatible (usually a decorator returns something that uses `*args` and `**kwargs`), the instance can be used as a replacement for the original function.

Normally the `__call__` method would call the wrapped function. Doing it in `__init__` is generally incorrect; `__init__` should store a reference to the wrapped function as an instance attribute, so that `__call__` can call it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix:

```
class myDecorator(object):
   def __init__(self, f):
      print ("inside myDecorator.__init__()")
      self.f = f #Store the function being wrapped

   def __call__(self):
      print ("inside myDecorator.__call__()")
      self.f() # Call the wrapped function
```

Comment: to accept the function's args use def __call__(self, *args,**kwargs): and pass them to f

Answer (score 0):

Hello The correct way to do this would be something like this 
you have a Metaclass > ---  Decoratorclass > --> Actual Class

```
    class Meta(type):
        """ Metaclass  """

        def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return instance

        def __init__(cls, name, base, attr):
            super(Meta, cls).__init__(name, base, attr)


    class counted(metaclass=Meta):

        """ counts how often a function is called """

        def __init__(self, func):
            self.func = func

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("Timer Start ")
            Tem = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("Timer End {} ".format(Tem))
            return Tem


    class Test(object):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            pass

        @counted
        def methodA():
            print("Method A")
            return "1111"


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        obj = Test()
        obj.methodA()
```